# What's stopping this table from filling up its whole container

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Basically [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/aVkC8/) works great on chrome and firefox but the marked table (marked with the "this table" comment) doesn't fill the whole container in IE. I want it to look like his brothers to the left. I've been looking at it for the last 30+ minutes wondering what in the world is causing it not to work. I could use the help of a 2nd pair of eyes

The whole thing is quite huge, the problem table is towards the end of the html.

Comment: Just based on jsFiddle's syntax highlighter, you may have a tag or two mis-matched that chrome/FF can account for, but IE doesn't know what to do with. (I'm not sure how accurate jsFiddle is with tag alignment, however)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other tables that are filling up the container all have a wrapper div with a height declared on them but its missing on that one table that is not stretching. Add it and it works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/aVkC8/1/

Oh and: Holy inline-css styles Batman!, you can greatly simplify your code with defined classes and styles for your table.

Comment: I was much more disorganized back when I wrote that but no time to fix it up now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using something like [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) in order to get consistency across browsers?

From the homepage:

> Normalize.css is a customisable CSS file that makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. We researched the differences between default browser styles in order to precisely target only the styles that need normalizing.